# hibernate session initialization very slow in production with many entities definition

Tags: performance, hibernate, spring-boot, session, initialization

I have a Spring Boot app with 296 persisted objects annotated by **@Entity** using Hibernate framework for persitence implementation. In developpement using eclipse on a Core i7-6700 (4x 3.4Ghz - 4Ghz Turbo, SSD), the SessionFactory is initialized in almost 6 seconds.

My production server is a virtualized windows server on a Xeon E5-2620v2 (6x 2,1GHz - 2.6Ghz, HDD (+ SSD cache)). I have no control about allocated resources by virtualization.

When I run my app on this server, it take about 25 seconds to instantiate the SessionFactory.

No speed problem when app is fully initialized: the execution speed of all webservices/databases queries is normal.

Naively I think hibernate create SQL Queries of basical CRUD operations when SessionFactory is instantiated.
I tried adding *@DynamicInsert* and *@DynamicUpdate* on all *@Entity* classes but it did not bring to me a better startup time and SessionFactory instantiation time is the same.

I use the following spring / hibernate / others pertinent libraries versions: (from my pom.xml)

```
<hibernate.version>5.4.5.Final</hibernate.version>
<spring.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springSecurity.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>
<springBoot.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</springBoot.version>
<mssql-jdbc.version>7.4.1.jre11</mssql-jdbc.version>
<apache-commons-dbcp2.version>2.5.0</apache-commons-dbcp2.version>
<eh-cache.version>2.10.6</eh-cache.version>
<javaassist.version>3.25.0-GA</javaassist.version>
```

This is my hibernate SessionFactory configuration (part of application.mssql.properties file):

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

# useless cause I use GenerationType.IDENTITY 
# for primary key (id) of all entities
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 20 

hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = false
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
hibernate.cache.provider_class = org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans = true
hibernate.cache.use_reference_entries = true
hibernate.connection.url =  jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master;user=usr;password=pwd;
hibernate.connection.username = usr
hibernate.connection.password = pwd

# Multitenancy configuration
hibernate.multiTenancy = SCHEMA
hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider = MultiTenantConnectionProvider
hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver = CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver
```

That is how I define my hibernate SessionFactory (I know that I can use standard JPA session factory but this app was made like that and I don't want to change that, moreover, I have simplified class content for more readeability):

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    excludeName = { 
        "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"
    }
)
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {
        // my packages list
    }
)
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.mssql.properties" })
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * @return SQL-Server pooled connection using apache dbcp2
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {    

        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

        ds.setUrl(this.env.get("hibernate.connection.url"));
        ds.setUsername(this.env.get("hibernate.connection.username"));
        ds.setPassword(this.env.get("hibernate.connection.password"));
        ds.setDriverClassName(this.env.get("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
        ds.setMaxIdle(10);
        ds.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(100);

        return ds;

    }


    /**
     * @return main sessionFactory (the mostly used sessionFactory in app)
     */
    @Primary
    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                                  MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                  CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("my.root.pojo.package");

        // get hibernate properties from this.env (application.mssql.properties file)
        Properties hibernateProperties = getHibernateProperties();

        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT, "SCHEMA");
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return sessionFactory;


        // FROM THIS POINT --->
    }

    /**
     * @return transactionManager for main sessionFactory
     */ 
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // ----> TO THIS POINT took 6 sec in development, 25 sec in production

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }


    // some other stuff: 
    //   - sessionFactory on another databases,
    //   - getHibernateProperties() implementation,
    //   - initServer() method annotated by @Bean(initMethod = "init")
    //   - etc ...
}
```

Is it normal to have this speed difference? 
Did I forgotten something in hibernate configuration ?
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: How much resources does your virtual server have?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli 
My virtual server have 4 vCPU (2.10 Ghz), 32 Gbytes of RAM (but I limit my app instance with  -Xms256m -Xmx512m - it's the same performances without RAM limitation). For the moment I don't know more about my virtual server resources. Do you thing it could be the problem source, then I should investigated?

Comment: Do you also limit XMX when you run it locally?

Comment: No, but I just tried and the SessionFactory instanciation time is the same (~ 6 sec)

Comment: You have a HDD not a SDD, right? And ist there a virus scanner ?

Comment: Yes I have an HDD on production. Windows defender is active but both root path (which contain the jar) and process java.exe is added to exclusion